# Fermat's Little Theorem when the exponent is less than the $p - 1$

Tags: modular-arithmetic

F.L.T. tells us:

$$a^{p-1} \equiv 1 \mod p$$

In all the cases I have seen, we are able to break down a larger exponent such that it will contain $a^{p-1}$. Like [examples](http://math.cmu.edu/~cargue/arml/archive/15-16/number-theory-09-27-15-solutions.pdf) 1 - 7 here.

But how would we handle an example where the exponent is smaller than $p-1$?

Ex:

$$9^9 \mod 31 $$

What I am thinking is:

$$9^9 = (3^2)^{9} = 3^{18}$$
$$3^{18} \mod 31$$

try squaring it: 
$$3^{36} = 3^{30}3^6 \mod 31$$
$$= 1* 3^6 \mod 31$$

take the square root:
$$3^3 \mod 31$$$$ 27 \mod 31 \neq 4 \mod 31$$

Which is wrong!!

Is there a way of manipulating $9^9$ in the example above?
Thanks!

Comment: There are two square roots of $3^6$: $\pm3^3$.

Comment: Good catch. But how do we know which is the correct one?

Comment: By [Euler's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_criterion) & quadratic reciprocity $\large\bmod 31\!:\,\ 3^{15}\equiv -1  \Rightarrow\, 3^{18}\equiv -3^3\equiv 4\ \ $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$9^9\equiv3^{18}\equiv(3^3)^6\equiv(-4)^6\equiv(-64)^2\equiv(-2)^2\equiv4\pmod{31}$